# Pandas from csv to sql in Django: OperationalError, table x has no column named y

Tags: python, django, csv, pandas, sqlite

I'm building a website to manage the data produced by household devices. The data is contained in .csv files, and there will be several hundreds/thousands of those to ingest over time.

The csv looks like this:

```
Timestamp, Address (64bit), Zone, Sensor Type, Data type, Value
12/23/16 02:05:30, some_64bit_address, 5, 0, 0, 255
```

I can read the csv and convert it to a pandas dataframe, but I'm having trouble saving it to sql.  I get an

> OperationalError at /import/: table FromCsv has no column named
>   Address (64bit).

I know there are several questions similar to this one but I haven't been able to find an answer that fixes my problem and I don't know what to try next.  I tried with and without `index_col=False` in `read_csv`, with and without `index=False` in `to_sql`, and I tried deleting the database and migration files and starting from scratch.  I'm using python 3.5, django 1.11, pandas 0.19.2 and sqlite3.

The view:

```
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.FILES.getlist("csv_files")
        dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")

        for fichier in files:
            # convert the file in memory to stringio
            decoded = fichier.read().decode('utf-8')
            io_string = StringIO(decoded)

            try:
                # convert to dataframe
                chunks = pd.read_csv(
                    filepath_or_buffer=io_string,
                    parse_dates=["Timestamp"],
                    date_parser=dateparse,
                    chunksize=500000
                )

                for chunk in chunks:
                    chunk.columns = [
                        "Timestamp",
                        "Address (64bit)",
                        "Zone",
                        "Sensor Type",
                        "Data type",
                        "Value"]

                    # save table in database
                    with sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3") as conn:
                        chunk.to_sql("FromCsv", con=conn, index=False, if_exists="append")

                messages.success(request, fichier.name)

            except pd.io.common.EmptyDataError:
                pass

        return render(request, "upload_done.html")
    return render(request, "import_data.html")
```

The model:

```
class RawData(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "FromCsv"

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    zone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sensor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.timestamp)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/smoky05/PycharmProjects/UbiosDataSite/data/views.py" in import_data
  62.                         chunk.to_sql("FromCsv", con=conn, index=False, if_exists="append")

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py" in to_sql
  1201.                    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in to_sql
  470.                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in to_sql
  1503.         table.insert(chunksize)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in insert
  664.                 self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)

File "/home/smoky05/.virtualenvs/ubiosData/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in _execute_insert
  1291.         conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /import/
Exception Value: table FromCsv has no column named Address (64bit)
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert csv to pandas dataframe and then save it? You can directly read csv line by line and save the information in each line by creating a model instance (without converting it to a pandas dataframe).

Comment: @gitblame Thank you for your suggestion, actually that was pretty much my first idea, but I had trouble going from `decoded` to the `csv.reader()`; I gave it another shot, discovered `csv.StringIO` and now it works, I can populate the database :-)  However, I was also trying to address the issue of performance; I know it's much faster to save a pandas dataframe directly to sql rather than iterating over its lines; would you know how both compare to reading the csv line by line and creating model instances?

Comment: If you're looking for performance, [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file) answer suggests using `pandas` to read csv and there's an efficient [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method in Django. But I haven't benchmarked how fast this combination is compared to python's built in csv library.

Comment: Seems like I was on the right path with the code in my question, using pandas to read the csv; I'll look into the `bulk_create()` method, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a GUI sqlite viewer, I found the problem: the table that is created uses the column names from the destination model, so renaming the dataframes's columns accordingly makes it work:

```
chunk.columns = [
                        "timestamp",
                        "address",
                        "zone",
                        "sensor",
                        "data_type",
                        "data_value"]
```

now it matches the model:

```
class RawData(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "FromCsv"

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    zone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sensor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data_type = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    data_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.timestamp)
```